# query-selector by inner Text

Tags: javascript

I have a button such as:

```html
<button>sign up</button>
```

I have to use innerText instead of ID or class.
how can I get this element by querySelector by innerText? like:

```js
document.querySelector(..???..)
```

this is for react unit test.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understood the use case. Maybe `document.getElementsByTagName("button").innerHTML;` ?

Comment: What library are you using for testing? `enzyme`? `react-testing-library`? Any how I would not recommend querying by content, rather find the button element.

Comment: react-testing-library

Answer (score 1):

1. `document.querySelectorAll` : get a `NodeList` of elements
2. `Array.from` : convert `NodeList` to `Array`
3. `arr.filter` : filter the array for elements having the corresponding innerText
4. `str.includes` or `str.match` : for String matching

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure you have to get a list of all possible elements and then loop through them an check the text yourself to determine if the text you're looking for exists.

if [XPATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) is an option, you can maybe use that (contains-clause of xpath)